# How to copy array dimensional

Tags: java

this is my first post, i always try to find the solution but i didnt find it.

I need to copy one array[][][] to copy[][][] but the copy is need to be more longer than the array.

I wrote this but dont copy like 0, just copy like NULL and made a exception.

8. Copia un array tridimensional de enteros a otro de mayor tamaño.

   ```
   int datos, datos2, datos3, datos4;

   System.out.println("De cuantos elementos quiere que sea el array?");
   datos=leerInt();
   System.out.println("De cuantos elementos quiere que sea el array bidimensional?");
   datos2=leerInt();
   System.out.println("De cuantos elementos quiere que sea el array tridimensional?");
   datos3=leerInt();
   int valor[][][]=new int[datos][datos2][datos3];



   for (int i=0;i<valor.length;i++){
       for (int j=0;j<valor[i].length;j++){
           for (int k=0;k<valor[i][j].length;k++){
               System.out.println("Introduce el valor para el array"+(i+1)+" de la parte bidimensional "+(j+1)+" de la parte tridimensional "+(k+1));
               datos4=leerInt();
               valor[i][j][k]=datos4;
           }
       }
   }

   int copia[][][]=Arrays.copyOf(valor, valor.length+2);

   for (int i=0; i < copia.length; i++) {
       for (int j=0; j < copia[i].length; j++) {
           for (int k=0; k < copia[i][j].length; k++) {
               System.out.println("Los valores copiado es: "+ copia[i][j][k]);

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I looked up but i only saw for normal array and not dimensional

Comment: Which means it doesn't apply dimensional, so you have to do it.

Comment: Lets say the original 3D array is 5x9x12. Do you want the new array to be 7x9x12, i.e. only add 2 to the first dimension *(seems to be what you're trying to do)*, or do you need it to be 7x11x14, i.e. add 2 to all 3 dimensions?

Comment: Thats my question, how?

Comment: i have 2x5x7 so i want to be 3x8x12 for example or 4x7x9 and show me something like '0' or NULL

Comment: We can't tell you your requirements. It is **your** code, so **you** have to know why you want to increase which dimension. There is no "natural" rule to follow. You want to grow your array dimensions (for a reason you are not telling us), so you have to tell us.

Comment: To figure out how, you first need to *fully* understand that Java doesn't have 3D arrays, only arrays-of-arrays. Do you understand that part? If not, then you should start by reading up more on how multi-dimensional arrays work in Java.

Comment: For you, I'd say the easiest solution is for you to create the new array using `new int[newD1][newD2][newD3]`, then copy the values using nested `for` loops.

Comment: @GhostCat Well im learning and im on the school so thats why im asking here, but ill ask to my teacher about it, it just a exercise.

Comment: @Andreas Yes i know, but my teacher told us to do this exercise but i cant copy one array to another array more bigger

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback, and welcome to upvote levels, which allows you to show even more appreciation for helpful input ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer is pretty simple, you only need to do these three things:

- create a new array, down to the last dimension, like you alrady do with `int valor[][][]=new int[datos][datos2][datos3];`
- the above gives you that "3 dim" array, with **all** elements pre-setted to 0 (because it is an array of int, there can't be NULL values in there)
- then you iterate your "old" array, and for each value, you "simply" decide where it should go to in the new, larger array

The dimensions of the new array, and that *mapping* function that you need completely depend on your requirements. We can't tell you that. You intend to solve some sort of problem, so determining how many "new" elements you need, and where exactly you want to copy in the old values completely depends on what *you* want to achieve. Which you didnt tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to @GhostCat i solved my problem

```
int datos, datos2, datos3, datos4;

    System.out.println("De cuantos elementos quiere que sea el array?");
    datos=leerInt();
    System.out.println("De cuantos elementos quiere que sea el array bidimensional?");
    datos2=leerInt();
    System.out.println("De cuantos elementos quiere que sea el array tridimensional?");
    datos3=leerInt();
    int valor[][][]=new int[datos][datos2][datos3];
    int copia[][][]=new int[datos][datos2+1][datos3+2];



    for (int i=0;i<valor.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<valor[i].length;j++){
            for (int k=0;k<valor[i][j].length;k++){
                System.out.println("Introduce el valor para el array"+(i+1)+" de la parte bidimensional "+(j+1)+" de la parte tridimensional "+(k+1));
                datos4=leerInt();
                valor[i][j][k]=datos4;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<valor.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<valor[i].length;j++){
            for (int k=0;k<valor[i][j].length;k++){
                copia[i][j][k]=valor[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i=0; i < copia.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < copia[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k < copia[i][j].length; k++) {
                System.out.println("Los valores copiado es: "+ copia[i][j][k]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont know how works this page, im new but i just click on my code because it is the answer, doesnt matter if give me point or not, i really dont care about point, but i'll give you the answer, thanks :D @GhostCat